app service how to change msbuild project
Using VS 2022 to build my .net 4.8 project.
I have cleaned up most of the warnings with only one or two left.
Currently the MSBuild project buid output verbosity level is set to Minimal

However, when I push the project to the app service pipeline and a build complets I get 140 warnings.
Some things as simple as
Warning CS1570: XML comment has badly formed XML -- 'End tag 'summary' does not match the start tag 'T'.'

which I dont need to see.
We are building the pipeline with a template.
How can I change the build output to match what I have in VS - Minimal
please

The VS settings only control MSBuild's output when you use MSBuild from within Visual Studio - it has nothing to do with C# project build warnings - nor with builds run on a CI service. ...and you should fix those C# build warnings too.

"How can I change the build output to match what I have in VS - Minimal" - That depends on how you're running msbuild in your CI environment - you haven't shown us your build script, so we can't really help you.

Thanks for the reply, but my Q was how do I change the setting on azure pipelines please?

You haven't posted the build script you're using with Azure Pipelines.

Thanks for the reply. Our YAML file is quite large, what tag am I looking for? there is no 'msbuildArgs' tag

I agree with Dai, You need to make changes to your Ci/Cd build pipeline. Here's how you can add the verbosity to minimal in Azure Devops yaml pipeline:-


Pipeline code:-
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - main

jobs:
- job: Build
  displayName: 'Build and Publish'
  pool:
    vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
  steps:
  - task: UseDotNet@2
    displayName: 'Install .NET Core SDK'
    inputs:
      version: '6.x'

  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: 'Restore Dependencies'
    inputs:
      command: 'restore'
      projects: '**/*.csproj'
      verbosityRestore: Minimal  # Setting restore verbosity to minimal

  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: 'Build Project'
    inputs:
      command: 'build'
      projects: '**/*.csproj'
      arguments: '--configuration Release'
      verbosityPack: Minimal
      

  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: 'Publish Project'
    inputs:
      command: 'publish'
      projects: '**/*.csproj'
      publishWebProjects: true
      arguments: '--configuration Release --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
      zipAfterPublish: true
      verbosityPack: Minimal
  - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
    displayName: 'Publish Artifact'
    inputs:
      targetPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
      artifactName: 'publishedApp'
      publishLocation: 'pipeline'

- job: Deploy
  displayName: 'Deploy to Azure Web App'
  dependsOn: Build
  pool:
    vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
  steps:
  - download: current
    artifact: 'publishedApp'

  - task: UseDotNet@2
    displayName: 'Install .NET Core SDK'
    inputs:
      version: '6.x'

  - task: AzureWebApp@1
    displayName: 'Azure Web App Deploy'
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: 'xxxx subscription (xxxxxxx6e97cb2a7)'
      appType: 'webApp'
      appName: 'silicon-webapp980'
      package: '$(Agent.BuildDirectory)/**/*.zip'
      deploymentMethod: 'auto'



thansk for the reply and sorry for the delay but sometimes you use verbosityPack: Minimal and sometimes you use verbosityRestore: Minimal how am I to know which to use and when?

Just checked your tags against my yaml file I dont have any of the tags that you dotask,displayNmae, input, addtype etc.... I know every file can be different but I am unsure where to add these verbosity level tags please

verbosity restore is used in restore task and verbosity pack is used in build task, You will have to try my yaml pipeline to build your project for verbosity set to minimal.
